# How to properly handle a 'body' jquery event to close a dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, menu

I'm trying to make a dropdown very similar to dropbox dashboard, where if you click the username a flyout menu appears. Clicking the username again will close the flyout (toggling it every time you click).

The one caveat is that clicking anywhere *except* on the flyout itself will also close it.

So far, I have it working almost, but not 100%. If you click on the actual 'body' element directly, it will close the flyout as it should. By this I mean my website has a .wrapper element which doesn't take up the full height of the page. Theres a thin strip down at the bottom with no actual element covering it, only the `<body>` tag. Any place where `.wrapper` or some other element takes up space (even a 100% width invisible wrapper), it will not close the window if you click on anything where there is an element (besides body).

javascript:

```
// FLYOUT menu 
$flyout = $('.flyout ul'),
 flyoutDuration = 120;

$('.flyout h3 a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $flyout.fadeToggle(flyoutDuration);
});

$(document).on('click',function(e) { 
    if ( $(e.target).parents($flyout).length === 0 ) { 
        $flyout.fadeOut(flyoutDuration); 
    }
});
```

HTML

```
<body>
    <div class="blackbar">
        <div class="container clearfix">
            <a href="/"><div class="icon logo"></div></a>
            <div class="flyout">
                <h3>
                    Welcome back, <a href="#">username</a>
                </h3>
                <div class="menu">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#"><div class="users"></div>Users</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><div class="groups"></div>Groups</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><div class="configuration"></div>Configuration</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><div class="logout"></div>Logout</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <! -- content here -->
    </div>
</body>
```

The expected behavior should be any element you click on that isnt a descendent of .flyout should close the window (including `.blackbar`, the logo, etc)

Comment: Did you try adding that wrapper to the selector : `$(document).add('.wrapper').on('click',function(e) { ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be honest - when I am doing something like this and I do not want clicks inside of the "box" to close the element - I prevent clicks from bubbling.

```
// FLYOUT menu 
$flyout = $('.flyout ul'),
 flyoutDuration = 120;

$('.flyout h3 a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $flyout.fadeToggle(flyoutDuration);
});

$('.flyout').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
});

$(document).on('click',function(e) { 
  if(flyout-open) {
        $flyout.fadeOut(flyoutDuration); 
    }
});
```

Comment: You are a superstar, exactly what I was looking for :)

Comment: one minor problem -- it seems this makes it so i can no longer click the actual links in the flyout menu (i believe its trigging preventDefault. the menu stays and the links dont follow, it just sits there). Do you know what I have to add?

Comment: nevermind, i just deleted the second preventDefault and it worked perfect. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Jquery Menu Click - on **click** anywhere on body will close the menu

In my case i wanted to close a drop down menu if its clicked primary link or outside the link i.e. anywhere on the html/body

http://jsfiddle.net/austinnoronha/k2Lwj/

```
var toggleClick = function(){

    var divObj = $(this).next();
    var nstyle = divObj.css("display");

    if(nstyle == "none"){
        divObj.slideDown(false,function(){
            $("html").bind("click",function(){
                divObj.slideUp();
                $("html").unbind("click");
            });
        });
    }
};

$(".clickme").click(toggleClick);
```