# How to make 2nd click close dropdown menu in Mobile Safari

Tags: jquery, mobile, drop-down-menu, safari

I have a relatively simple dropdown menu which I have mouseenter and mouseleave events set up for. The menu works great, however on mobile Safari clicking on the link which triggers the menu a '2nd time' (after the menu has been opened) does not close it. I've tried adding a click event to the html or body to trigger closing of the menu but this doesn't appear to work.

My HTML:

```
<ul>
<li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Toggle dropdown</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li>This is my sub menu</li>
        <li>And another item</li>
        <li>And one more</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Just another link</a></li>
```

My CSS (This bit's really complicated):

```
ul.dropdown-menu { display: none; }
```

My jQuery:

```
$(document).on({ mouseenter: function(){
        $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(250).fadeIn(100);
        $(this).addClass('open');
    }, mouseleave: function() {
        $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(50).fadeOut(50);
        $(this).removeClass('open');
    }}, 'ul li.dropdown');
```

I also threw this all up in a Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/EtS8E/1/

I had kinda ssumed that adding a click event to the li itself would allow me to trigger a close but alas, that doesn't give me the desired result either.

I've been Googling this for what seems like hours and have found a couple of related question here with answers (for example: [How to properly handle a 'body' jquery event to close a dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13237690/how-to-properly-handle-a-body-jquery-event-to-close-a-dropdown)) but neither seem to work as described

Any ideas? :!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be of any help to anyone but I'll post it here for clarity. In the end I fixed the problem using the following.

```
$(document).on({ mouseenter: function(e){
        if (!iOSdevice) {
            $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(250).fadeIn(100);
            $(this).addClass('open');
        }
    }, mouseleave: function(e) {
        if (!iOSdevice) {
            $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(50).fadeOut(50);
            $(this).removeClass('open');
        }
    }, click: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // Prevents the default click event
        if ($(this).hasClass('open')) {
            $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(50).fadeOut(50);
            $(this).removeClass('open');
        } else {
            // Reset all other open dropdowns
            resetDropDowns();
            // Open this dropdown
            $(this).addClass('open');
            $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(250).fadeIn(100);
        }
    }}, 'header nav ul li.dropdown:not(.disabled)');
```

The iOSdevice var is true/false depending on the browser type.